# Need Regular expression - perl

Tags: perl

I am looking for a regx for below expression:

```
my $text = "1170 KB/s (244475 bytes in 2.204s)";  # I want to retrieve last ‘2.204’ from this String.

$text =~ m/\d+[^\d*](\d+)/;   #Regexp

my $num = $1;

print " $num ";
Output:
204
```

But I need 2.204 as output, please correct me.
Can any one help me out?

Comment: Check parentheses in regex.

Comment: The regex is doing exactly what you asked it to: It is matching digits `\d+`, followed by *one* non-digit or star `[^\d*]`, followed by digits `\d+`. The only thing that matches that in your string is `204`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The regex is doing exactly what you asked it to: It is matching digits `\d+`, followed by *one* non-digit or star `[^\d*]`, followed by digits `\d+`. The only thing that matches that in your string is `204`.

If you want a quick fix, you can just move the parentheses:

```
m/(\d+[^\d*]\d+)/
```

This would (with the above input) match what you want. A more exact way to put it would be:

```
m/(\d+\.\d+)/
```

Of course this will match any float precision number, so if you can have more of those, that's not a good idea. You can shore it up by using an anchor, like so:

```
m/(\d+\.\d+)s\)/
```

Where `s\)` forces the match to occur at only that place. Further strictures:

```
m/\(\d+\D+(\d+\.\d+)s\)/
```

You might also want to account for the possibility of your target number *not* being a float:

```
m/\(\d+\D+(\d+\.?\d*)s\)/
```

By using `?` and `*` we allow for those parts not to match at all. This is not recommended to do unless you are using anchors. You can also replace everything in the capture group with `[\d.]+`.

If you are not fond of matching the parentheses, you can match the text:

```
m/bytes in ([\d.]+)s/
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd go with the second marker as indicator where you are in the string:

```
my ($num) = ($text =~ /(\d+\.\d+)s/);
```

with explanations:

```
/(    # start of matching group
 \d+  # first digits
 \.   # a literal '.', take \D if you want non-numbers
 \d+  # second digits
 )/x  # close the matching group and the regex
```

You had the matching groups wrong. Also the `[^\d]` is a bit excessive, generally you can negate some of the backspaced special classes (`\d`,`\h`, `\s` and `\w`) with their respective uppercase letter.

Answer (score 0):

Try this regex:

```
$text =~ m/\d+[^\d]*(\d+\.?\d*)s/;
```

That should match 1+ digits, a decimal point if there is one, 0 or more decimal places, and make sure it's followed by a "s".

Comment: `[\d]` better written as `\D`. Also, this would match any series of digits followed by `s`.